# C# Invoke generic method with casted property as parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, properties, casting

I have a generic class with a generic method:

```
public class GenericClass<T> where T : class
{
   public void GenericMethod<T>(T item)
   {
      // do work here
   }
}
```

I also have an object with multiple properties, some of which can be other objects:

```
public class TestObject
{
   public ChildObject ChildObject { get; set; }
}
```

I am then attempting to use a generic method which will reflect through TestObject and call GenericMethod for all properties that are in and of themselves custom classes such as ChildObject (I do have a way of determining this based on inheritance, however for the sake of keeping it simple did not include that code for this example):

```
public void ReflectingMethod<T>(T item)
{
   var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();

   foreach (var property in properties)
   {
      var type = property.PropertyType;

      dynamic propertyModel = property.GetValue(model, null);

      var castedObject = Convert.ChangeType(propertyModel, type);
      var genericClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(type));
      var method = genericClass.GetType().GetMethod("GenericMethod", new [] { type });

      method.Invoke(castedObject, null);
   }
}
```

The problem is that whether I attempt to change property's type (as shown in the above example) or I pass property directly to method.Invoke, such as:

```
method.Invoke(propertyModel, null);
```

I still receive the same error:

> Object does not match target type.

At RunTime method is:

> GenericMethod(TestProject.ChildObject)

And castedObject is:

> TestProject.ChildObject

I am confused as to why I am getting the error I am, when it would appear that the casted object is exactly of the type that the method is looking for.

**EDIT 1**
Included the call to GetValue that I had originally left out when posting the question.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. The cause of the error is obvious: `property` is a `PropertyInfo` object, and there's no reason to expect it to be convertable to the type that property _returns_. Maybe you meant to get `property.GetValue(item)` first? But in that case, I would not expect you to need to call `Convert.ChangeType()` at all. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, along with a precise description of what the code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: My apologies. In my attempt to simplify the code for the sake of posting here, I forgot to include the call to GetValue. However I am using GetValue into a dynamic in order to get the actual object before casting. And yes you would think I would not need to cast the object, however I did so solely for the purpose of verifying that regardless the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call

```
  method.Invoke(castedObject, null);
```

is incorrect. It should be

```
  method.Invoke(genericClass, new object[] { castedObject });
```

Since you are trying to call an instance method, the first argument to [Invoke(object, object[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) must be the `this` instance. For static method, pass `null` as first argument. Method arguments are always passed via the second `object[]` argument of the `Invoke` method.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for.